# Finding the norm of a given operator

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, operator-theory

Let $$X=C[0,2] \ , ||{\Psi}||_\infty=\underset{a\leq x\leq2}{max}|\Psi(x)|$$ .

Then we have the operator $A$ which is the multiplication by $x$ operator:

$$A\Psi(x)=x\Psi(x)$$

Let $\Psi(x)=\cos x$ , then $A\Psi(x)=x\cos x$. Find  $||{A}||$.

*Proposed solution:*

By the definition, we have
$$||{A\cos x}||\leq\underset{0\leq x\leq 2}{max}|x\cos x |$$

which gives

$$||{A\cos x}||\leq\underset{0\leq x\leq 2}{max}|x|\cdot\underset{0\leq x\leq 2}{max}|\cos x|$$

$$||{A\cos x}||\leq c||\cos x ||$$

and when

$$ ||\cos(x)|| = \left[\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(x)\cos(x)dx\right]^{1/2}=\sqrt{\pi}$$

we get

$$||{A\cos x}||\leq c\sqrt{\pi}$$,
where $c\leq 2$.

But something is fishy here,  since the interval is [0,2], $c$  should then be  $\leq 2$. However, I have really found the norm of $Ax$, not $A$. Is there a better answer than this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you claiming that usually the norm of an operator is smaller than or equal to $1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos see the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|A \Psi(x)| =x |\Psi(x)| \le 2 ||\Psi||_{\infty}.$ Hence

$$||A \Psi||_{\infty} \le 2 ||\Psi||_{\infty}.$$

This gives

$$||A|| \le 2.$$

Now let $ \Psi(x)=\frac{1}{2}x.$  Then $||\Psi||_{\infty}=1$ and $A \Psi(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2.$ Thus

$$||A \Psi||_{\infty} =2 =2 ||\Psi||_{\infty}.$$

Therefore

$$||A||=2.$$

Comment: Thanks Fred. Can one automatically conclude that the norm is the max of the interval, since the operator is $x$? While for a function which was parabolic, i.e. $T=x^2$, this would not be the same case, it would be $\sqrt{2}$?